# Sampling according to a product of a known density and a probability function

Tags: sampling, monte-carlo, importance-sampling, accept-reject

Given a known density $p(x)$, I'd like to generate samples according to $q(x) \propto p(x) f(x)$, where $f(x)$ is some probability function, $\forall x f(x) \in [0, 1]$, e.g., a sigmoid function.
One way to generate such samples is by using a type of rejection sampling where we first generate $x \sim p$ then accept / reject based on the value of $f(x)$.

However, I'd like to use $q(x)$ as a proposal density in the context of importance sampling to generate samples that are rare under $p$. So, this rejection sampling approach would be very inefficient and essentially defeat the purpose of using importance sampling.

Is there a more efficient way to sample according to $q(x)$ as above, somehow using the fact that $f(x)$ is a probability function, e.g., a sigmoid function?
Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is $f$ a probability density or a cumulative density?

Comment: @jbowman For the specific problem I'm looking at, it's more a scoring function whose output is in [0, 1] e.g., $f(x)$ being how likely $x$ to meet some criteria. Perhaps I shouldn't have called $f$ a probability function.

Comment: There are many potential algorithms that might be used. If you can find a suitable envelope for $q$ there's accept-reject (and a variety of potential ways to obtain some). If you have a suitable approximation to use in a proposal distribution and don't mind dependence in your generated values you may be able to use Metropolis-Hastings. etc etc

Comment: "Probability function" has no particular meaning in this setting. For rare events, cross-entropy is a way to build a better proposal than $p(\cdot)$